# Comunication between LANS using layer 3 switch only

Tags: link-layer

I have a LAN-A with VLANs 10,15 and a layer 3 switch-A used to communicate between VLANs 10 and 15. This LAN is working OK.

I have a LAN-B with VLANs 60,65 and a layer 3 switch-B used to communicate between VLANs 60 and 65. This LAN is working OK too.

Question: Do I need an additional layer 3 switch or an additional router to communicate devices between LAN-A and LAN-B? (let's say vlan 10 device with vlan 60 device). Or can this be achieved just by configuring switches A and B?

Thanks.
Arthur

Comment: Layer 3 switch = Router. Do you need another router? No, you already have 2 routers built into both Layer 3 switches.

Answer (score 1):

No, as long as switch A and switch B have some method of connection (e.g. trunk link ) between them.  You would need to enter routes on both sides pointing to the SVIs of the corresponding VLAN.  If needed, you could control traffic with ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. 
The interfece between switches was missing. I just created it and  ativated the RIP protocol for that interface. Actually I have redundant layer 3 switches in each LAN, so the network is quite more complex, but now is running!!

Thanks again